# Powershell script to delete folders not specified in a list

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a file with a list of folder names like this:

Folder1
Folder2
Folder3

How can I delete all folders from a directory except for these that are listed in the file?

Comment: There are quite a few examples on the web. You should be able to find quite a few examples by just googling.

Answer (score 0):

This is useful for you

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' -Recurse -exclude somefile.txt | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\temp\foldertokeep*'} | sort length -Descending | Remove-Item -force